# Target specific div class instead of nextElementSibling

Tags: javascript

I'm building a super simple javascript accordion. Here's how it currently looks.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Instead of the panel being targeted using `this.nextElementSibling;`, I'd like to target it with a class name.

I've replaced `this.nextElementSibling;` with `var panel = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");`.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was expecting my adjustment to find the class `.panel` instead of the next sibling, but I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined".

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) return a `HTML Collection` which does not have a `style` property and `.style.display` is `undefined`

to access an element, you'll need to do `document.getElementsByClassName("panel")[0]` ( or `[1]` , `[2]` ... )

doing `document.getElementsByClassName` will give you all the elements in the document, you need to select the `parent` of the clicked button and run the query on it

```
var parent = evt.target.parentElement;
var panel = parent.getElementsByClassName("panel")[0];
```

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var parent = evt.target.parentElement;
    var panel = parent.getElementsByClassName("panel")[0];
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work now.
Added `let` at string 3 and `[i]` at string 6; string 2 is removed.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
//var i;
for (let i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = document.getElementsByClassName("panel")[i];
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```